# Контроллер не вызывается из шаблона opencart?

Tags: opencart

Создал контроллер head.php в папке catalog/controller/common:

```
    <?php
class ControllerCommonHead extends Controller {
  public function index() {
    var_dump(123);
    die;
    
    return $this->load->view('common/head', $data);
  }
}
```

Вызываю его из обычного home.twig:
{{ head }}

В результате ничего, Если перейти по http:// localhost/?route=common/head все работает

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было в catalog/controller/home.php указать этот контроллер:

```
$data['head'] = $this->load->controller('common/head');
```